# Assigning String as Google App Engine Entity Key

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa, primary-key

I searched a lot. Still I am not able to understand how to assign a String to **Google App Engine** Entity class id(Key).

So I have:

```
Key id;
```

And

```
setId(String id) { 
    // I know that here I can use id = KeyFactory.createKey("",""); 
}
```

But I don't know how to use `createKey` method here to assign my string to id. Please consider User here as my `Entity` class name.

P.S. I am using **JPA**.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure of your entity is looking but this works well for me.,

```
@Entity
class Person{
    @Id String personId; 
    String firstName;
}
```

Comment: Thank you I have above as @Id Key personId; Because I have oneToMany relationship I thought I should keep it as key.

Comment: Key is a class by itself, Here is some information that would help hot to covert Key to a String. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/keyclass. Cheers.